# Difference in if statement selector

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I don't understand the difference between this condition:

```
if ($("div")) { /* code */ }
```

and

```
if ($("div").length) { /* code */ }
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Answer (score 2):

The first `if` condition is incorrect as `$('div')` returns an object. Type coercion to a boolean from an object - even an empty one - will *always* equate to true.

The second condition is checking the `length` property of the object, which is an integer. Type coercion on that type will be `false` if the value is `0` and `true` for anything else, either positive or negative, hence it works.